Polars : output of aggregate function (sum)
When I make the sum of the "Price" column for a subset of rows, I get the correct answer.
ca = [df.filter((pl.col('Created') <= datum[j]) & (pl.col('Year') == jaar[j])).select(pl.sum('Price')) for j in range(aantaljaren)]

However, I get it an an object, surrounded by the usual polars formatting we can see on the screen. So I can't use the elements of the ca list in further calculations.
How can I get rid of all this extra formatting of polars print and just produce a float with my formula?
This is the content of ca[3]:
shape: (1, 1)  
┌──────────┐  
│ Price    │
│ ---      │    
│ f64      │  
╞══════════╡  
│ 75395.84 │  
└──────────┘  

I just want 75395.84.
I tried .item() after the formula. No change.
I tried to convert to float => type error.

Can you provide a minimal runnable example? The "proper" approach will depend on the exact task. We don't know if datum / jaar are other dataframes for example, or how ca is intended to be used in further calculations.

jaar = [2020,2021,2022,2023,2024,2025]
maand = 7
dag = 26
aantaljaren = len(jaar)
datum = [date(jaar[i], maand, dag) for i in range(aantaljaren)]
ca = [df.filter(
(pl.col("Created") <= datum[j])
& (pl.col("Year") == jaar[j])
& (pl.col("Status") == "Booked")
).select(pl.sum("Price")).item()
for j in range(aantaljaren)]        This is the code that works. If you take away .item() it produces my problem (so I found the solution, but I don't think it's very elegant.

That looks like you want a yearly sum of booked prices before the date? e.g. something like df.with_columns(Result = pl.col.Price.filter(pl.col.Created.dt.month() <= 7, pl.col.Created.dt.day() <= 26, pl.col.Status == "Booked").sum().over("Year"))  - Generally you dont want to materialize results into Python variables using .item() - Will you be using these values in further Polars queries?

No, I don't want to use the results in queries but to integrate them into a dataframe to make further calculations with them.   Thanks for sharing how you would solve this.  I'll take a good look at it to learn from you (I just started with Polars 2 d ago, you can probably tell :-)).   I want to use this code to follow up my Airbnb bookings throughout the year to check how I'm doing vs. previous years.

I found the solution. It is using .item() on the whole expression, not concatenated to the expression as I did previously.
ca = [(df.filter((pl.col('Created') <= datum[j]) & (pl.col('Year') == jaar[j])).select(pl.sum('Price'))).item() for j in range(aantaljaren)]

I still feel it's not very elegant to have formatting info mixed with the result of a calculation and needing to take an extra step to remove it.

I think there is a misunderstanding: There is no "formatting info mixed with the result of a calculation". The string representation of python objects depends on the underlying type. In general, a filtered pl.DataFrame is still a pl.DataFrame and not a python float. This makes sense as usually, you'd try to keep all information in polars dataframe objects and avoid converting to native python types altogether.

You are right. My remark shows that I'm a complete newbie in Polars. I bought the book 'Effective Polars' and I'll work through that before making any more of these comments. :-)

No worries - stackoverflow is also there to help with such misunderstandings. Great that you got the book!

You can try ca[3].to_list()[0] where it converts the third element which is a polars Series to a list and then it  extract the  first element.

Thanks for the suggestion, but It doesn't work. But even if it did, I would find it highly inefficient and very not-elegant. I feel I'm missing something obvious here. I can't imagine that it's the Polar's developers intent to send formatting info integrated in the result. Could it be a setting somewhere that I missed?
